# What GPU does the Intel N3700 have?

Tags: gpu, intel-graphics

I have an Intel N3700 CPU, but I can't figure out which GPU I have.

CPU-Z says "Intel HD Graphics," but which version?

Here is a screenshot from CPU-Z:

[image]

Comment: [`Intel HD Graphics`](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-HD-Graphics-Braswell.146746.0.html) **is** the model.  This same GPU was rebranded to `HD Graphics 400` and `HD Graphics 405` when the (J/N)3710.  So CPU-Z is actually displaying the correct information.

Comment: use GPU-Z to get more details about the GPU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units#Eighth_generation), this is an 8th-generation Intel GPU, of the [Cherryview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silvermont#List_of_Airmont_processors) architecture.  Its model name is "`HD Graphics`" - later processors have similar GPUs, called "`HD Graphics 400`" and "`HD Graphics 405`".

It has 16 execution units running at 400-700 MHz, and video decode acceleration.

Answer (score 8):

You have [integrated graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit#Integrated_graphics_solutions), which means there's no discrete graphics card in your computer, but instead the CPU serves as a graphics card, using your system RAM rather than dedicated RAM on a graphics card.

If you wish to see the version of your integrated graphics, go to `Device Manager`, expand `Display Adapters`, right click on `Intel(R) HD Graphics Family`, and hit `Properties`. In the `Drivers` tab, you should find the version of your graphics driver for your display.

For more information, see `Graphics Specifications` on [your processor's page](http://ark.intel.com/products/87261/Intel-Pentium-Processor-N3700-2M-Cache-up-to-2_40-GHz) on Intel's website.

Comment: And before you comment, @KDev... "Intel HD Graphics" is all Intel calls it. Compare [your CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/87261/Intel-Pentium-Processor-N3700-2M-Cache-up-to-2_40-GHz) with, say... the [i7-6820HQ](http://ark.intel.com/products/88970/Intel-Core-i7-6820HQ-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz). My [Surface 3's CPU/GPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/85475/Intel-Atom-x7-Z8700-Processor-2M-Cache-up-to-2_40-GHz) reports the same way.

Comment: As pointed out the GPU **is** the `Intel HD Graphics` just from Braswell generation product line..

Answer (score 1):

The Intel HD Graphics is an integrated GPU inside the CPU. So if you know the CPU type you can look up the information on the graphics that are embedded in that CPU.

Comment: @FrankThomas: That is providing the information.  There's no *undisclosed model number*, this particular iGPU's model name doesn't have a number in it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Win+R to bring up `Run` dialog and enter `dxdiag`. This will bring up DirectX Diagnostic Tool. Go to `Display` tab and there you can see model and driver info about your graphics hardware.

Comment: it says only "Intel HD"

Comment: there's no where a number of intel hd

Comment: Please refer to : http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html?iid=dc_iduu and http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/graphics-drivers/000005510.html for identification methods and driver updates